# How to get data from webpage to NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, nsstring

Is it possible (using ASIHTTPRequest or something) to get data from webpage and save it to NSString variable?

I have following code on the webpage:

```
<span id="ctl06_ctl06_spDailySMSSection">RANDOM TEXT xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <strong><span id="ctl06_ctl06_spNumberOfDailySMSLeft"></span></strong> AGAIN RANDOM TEXT.</span>
```

how can I get data from field **ctl06_ctl06_spNumberOfDailySMSLeft** and use it in iOS app?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using a UIWebView, or do you wish to download a page in the background and extract some data ? This is the important factor here for choosing the right solution solution.

Answer (score 2):

To do this correctly, you need an NSXMLParser that works with the correct tags and takes in the attribute you need parsed. If you're looking for a less generic solution:

```
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your.url"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Do you have any examples or something how to do that? Because Im newbie in iOS programming, so i have no idea where to start from.

Comment: In the generic solution u posted I dont understand how to specify which field I want to use in my nsstring

Comment: Parsing XML files is a broad subject, here's a good tutorial: http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/

Comment: and what if the file I want to get data from is not xml? I want to get data from webpage. is it important difference?

Comment: Then you could just use the string method I gave you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webview to load that webpage, following code will help you:

```
- (BOOL)webView: (UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

 NSString* urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[request URL]];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JavaScript if you display the page in a webview:

```
NSString *innerTextOfSpan = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('ctl06_ctl06_spDailySMSSection').innerText"];
```

If you do not intend to display the web site anyway, I highly suggest going with stavash answer.

If the page structure is simple enough, a simple Regex might work.